# Using a CASE statement in SQL to pull the previous week

Tags: sql, case

I am trying to make a new column with the previous week sales and if its week 1 of the period then 0.

This is just returning all 0's. Any suggestions?

```
SUM(CASE 
    WHEN GMR.AMC_WEEK <> 1 AND GMR.AMC_WEEK = GMR.AMC_WEEK -1 THEN GMR.NET_SALES_AMT
    ELSE 0 END) AS PREV_WK_SLS,
```

Comment: `GMR.AMC_WEEK = GMR.AMC_WEEK -1` can never be true. Please show us the entire query, along with sample data and desired results, as tabular text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't use `case` for this purpose.  I am guessing you want one of these:

```
lag(GMR.NET_SALES_AMT, 1, 0) over (order by amc_week)
```

or:

```
lag(sum(GMR.NET_SALES_AMT), 1, 0) over (order by amc_week)
```

The difference is whether the amount actually needs to be aggregated.

Comment: Great thanks, Is there a way to lag the sales by week but also make sure my other variables match. for example i want to make sure sales are lagging by week for the correct year and department.

Comment: @JimmyLarkin . . . Assuming you have data for every week, you would using `partition by year, department`.

Comment: Hi Gordon I got this to work by using the lag over partition and order by thank you!!!